# Spring MVC pagination

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Прикрутил к простому CRUD приложению пейджинг следующим образом:

- В users.jsp:

  ```
  <div id="pagination">
  <c:url value="/users" var="prev">
      <c:param name="page" value="${page-1}"/>
  </c:url>
  <c:if test="${page > 1}">
      <a href="<c:out value="${prev}" />" class="pn prev">Prev</a>
  </c:if>
  <c:forEach begin="1" end="${maxPages}" step="1" varStatus="i">
      <c:choose>
          <c:when test="${page == i.index}">
              <span>${i.index}</span>
          </c:when>
          <c:otherwise>
              <c:url value="/users" var="url">
                  <c:param name="page" value="${i.index}"/>
              </c:url>
              <a href='<c:out value="${url}" />'>${i.index}</a>
          </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
  </c:forEach>
  <c:url value="/users" var="next">
      <c:param name="page" value="${page + 1}"/>
  </c:url>
  <c:if test="${page + 1 <= maxPages}">
      <a href='<c:out value="${next}" />' class="pn next">Next</a>
  </c:if>
  ```

На этой же странице кроме списка юзеров есть форма для их добавления/правки, ну и в таблице юзеров кнопки для каждой позиции:

```
<td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${user.id}'/>">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="<c:url value='/remove/${user.id}'/>">Delete</a></td>
```

- В контроллере:

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView listUsers(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer page) {
      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("users");

      List<User> users = userService.listUsers();
      PagedListHolder<User> pagedListHolder = new PagedListHolder<User>(users);
      pagedListHolder.setPageSize(pageSize);
      modelAndView.addObject("maxPages", pagedListHolder.getPageCount());

      if(page==null || page < 1 || page > pagedListHolder.getPageCount())
          page=1;

      modelAndView.addObject("page", page);

      if(page == null || page < 1 || page > pagedListHolder.getPageCount()){
          pagedListHolder.setPage(0);
          modelAndView.addObject("listUsers", pagedListHolder.getPageList());
      }
      else if(page <= pagedListHolder.getPageCount()) {
          pagedListHolder.setPage(page-1);
          modelAndView.addObject("listUsers", pagedListHolder.getPageList());
      }

      modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());

      return modelAndView;
  }
  ```

На этом этапе все работает, список разбит на страницы, навигация работает, НО находясь например на 2ой странице удаляем юзера

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{id}")
public String removeUser(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    this.userService.removeUser(id);
    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

удаление проходит успешно, но отображение списка юзеров сбрасывается на 1ую страницу. То же самое и с операциями добавления/правки.
Понятно, ведь в каждом случае

> return "redirect:/users";

без параметра запроса с номером страницы.

Я пока еще не силен ни в JSP, ни в Spring. Подскажите, как этот параметр можно передавать и оперировать им в контроллере?

Спасибо!

Comment: Мне кажется что это сделать проще javascript'ом! Просто будете посылать на сервер команду удаления юзера оставаясь на текущей страницы без ее перезагрузки

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но разве JSP без перезагрузки отобразит измененный список? Listener наверное нужен, да?

Comment: Если юзать скрипты то всю страницу преобразите без перезагрузки, опять же список и скорее всего всю пагинацию логичней будет на JS

Comment: Логично. Попробую всю страницу переделать на JS.

Comment: Что бы сильно не напрягаться на первых порах по поводу фронтенда(ой меня сейчас тапками забросают) попробуйте JQuery с его DataTable там и простенькая пагинация реализована и куча еще чего!

Comment: Спасибо, возьму на заметку

Comment: jquery не актуально уже много лет. не тратьте не него время. выбирайте `vuejs` или `reatcjs`

Answer (score 0):

В проектах используем заголовок `X-Range: 0-19/300`.
Где 0-19 - отображаемые записи (с 0 по 19) и 300 - всего записей. Всего выставляется сервером, при ответе.

В контроллере такой заголовок легко достать из запроса и ограничивать им результирующий набор.

На клиенте используется JS для асинхронных запросов.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой, но не самый надёжный способ - это брать заголовок [REFERER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer), указывающий на адрес, с которого пришёл запрос, и отсылать на него:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{id}")
public String removeUser(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.userService.removeUser(id);

    return Optional
             .ofNullable(request.getHeader("referer"))
             .map(url -> "redirect:" + url)
             .orElse("redirect:/users/");  // На случай, если заголовок не установлен
}
```

Более надёжный вариант - это явно передавать в контроллер удаления страницу, на которую надо вернутся

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{id}")
public String removeUser(@PathVariable("id") int id,
                         @RequestParam(required = false, default = "1") int page) {
    this.userService.removeUser(id);

    String url = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodName(UserController.class,
                                                        "listUsers", page)
                                        .build()
                                        .toUriString();
    return "redirect:" + url;
}
```